# Angular2 Left Nav

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a side bar and I want its children to show up when the user clicks on it the parent. So when the user clicks on LinkTest I want its corresponding  to be display block.
Below is the Angular and Typescript code.
http://jsfiddle.net/2dwvLg9u/

```
<nav appMenu class="navmenu navmenu-default" role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li #testElem><a href="#">LinkTest</a>
      <ul class="hidden" #testElem1>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Below is the typescript code -**

```
import { Directive, Renderer2, OnInit, ElementRef, HostListener, HostBinding, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMenu]'
})
export class MenuDirective implements OnInit{

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit(){

  }
  @ViewChild('testElem') elRef:ElementRef;
  @HostListener('click') click(eventData: Event) {

    this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'display', 'block');


  }
}
```

Comment: I think the main issue is how I have setup the ViewChild

Comment: just added a jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution without a directive. It can be done inside the component view directly with the use of flag property to show/hide the sub-options and `*ngIf` based on that.
This solution has a small culprit of acting the same on the child node click, i.e. close the parent node on child node click. But this can be avoided. To block it we need to call `event.stopPropagation()` on the child click. 
Take a look:

**HTML**

```
<li (click)="showChild=!showChild" #testElem>
    <a href="#">LinkTest</a>
    <ul *ngIf="showChild" class="hidden" #testElem1> 
        <li (click)="onChildClick($event)"> //repeat it all for all child nodes
            <a href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
 ...
```

**Typescript**

```
  showChild;
  ...
  onChildClick(event){
    event.stopPropagation(); // this will prevent parent node closing on child node click
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypdmr9)

Comment: I added some more explanation